# Python menu integration error

Tags: python, syntax, menu

So, I have been trying to make a Skype multi-tool in Python which I am just starting with. I have the code for one program which works, but I cannot figure out how to put it into a menu.

Here is the code I get:

```
import time
import urllib2
ans=True
while ans:
print("""
1. Skype resolver
2. Option 2
3. Option 3
4.Exit/Quit
""")
ans=raw_input("What would you like to do? ")
if ans=="1":(
def getSkype():
input = '> '
print "Please enter a skype name: "
skypename = raw_input(input)
print "Skype name: %s" % skypename
time.sleep(2.5)
url = "http://APIOnly.com/skype.php?username=%s" % skypename
req = urllib2.Request(url)
response = urllib2.urlopen(req)
return response.read()

if __name__ == "__main__":
skypeip = getSkype()
print "IP: %s" % skypeip
print "Press [Enter] to continue"
raw_input()
 )
  time.sleep(20)
elif ans=="2":
  print("Option 2")
elif ans=="3":
  print("\n Option 3")
elif ans=="4":
  print("\n Goodbye") 
  ans = None
else:
       print("\n Not Valid Choice Try again")
```

It tells me that `def` is an invalid syntax.

How do I fix this and what did I do wrong?

Comment: Please fix your indentation. And why are you defining a function inside an if statement?

Comment: Where? Sorry but I just started python...

Answer (score 0):

Here is a properly indented code. But, do not forget that, in Python, the indentation of your code has a semantic meaning, so you cannot afford to get a "non-indented" code.

```
import time
import urllib2

ans=True

while ans:
    print("""
      1. Skype resolver
      2. Option 2
      3. Option 3
      4.Exit/Quit
    """)
    ans=raw_input("What would you like to do? ")
    if ans=="1":(
        def getSkype():
            input = '> '
            print("Please enter a skype name: ")
            skypename = raw_input(input)
            print("Skype name: %s" % skypename)
            time.sleep(2.5)
            url = "http://APIOnly.com/skype.php?username=%s" % skypename
            req = urllib2.Request(url)
            response = urllib2.urlopen(req)
            return response.read()

        if __name__ == "__main__":
            skypeip = getSkype()
            print("IP: %s" % skypeip)
            print("Press [Enter] to continue")
            raw_input()
        )
        time.sleep(20)
    elif ans=="2":
        print("Option 2")
    elif ans=="3":
        print("\n Option 3")
    elif ans=="4":
        print("\n Goodbye") 
        ans = None
    else:
        print("\n Not Valid Choice Try again")
```